# gitbook init Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be

Tags: gitbook

node: v14.0.0

CLI version: 2.3.2

GitBook version: 3.2.3

Windows10

When execute `gitbook init` in an empty folder, it pops up:

```
$ gitbook init
warn: no summary file in this book
info: create SUMMARY.md

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Promise
```

And there is no "SUMMARY.md" created...
How could it be fixed？Thanks！

Comment: I received the same error on my setup with Node 14.1.0. However, `gitbook build` and `gitbook serve` commands work anyway. Have you tried to build your docs with `gitbook build`? Any errors?

Comment: `gitbook build` and `gitbook serve` commands work fine. But `gitbook init` goes wrong, and I can't manage the summary of the book... I have to turn to use Docsify, which is pretty good as well.

Comment: `gitbook init` creates `readme.md` and `summary.md` files, nothing more. If the command fails, you can create SUMMARY.md manually and use `gitbook build` to build your docs.
Anyway, switching to a modern static-site generator is a good idea, as GitBook is heavily outdated (more than 2 years).

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem just as you. **Switch back from latest node version to 12.18.1 LTS.**

And everything gonna be ok.

Comment: I want you to know I know the truth, of course I know it...
I would be nothing without you...
Did you ever know that you're my hero?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to convert markdown files to an e-book?  If so, [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) is an alternative.

> pandoc -o js_functional.epub --metadata title="Functional JavaScript"
> *.md

If you want mobi format, [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) is a good converter.

Answer (score 0):

npm install -g gitbook-summary
and cd to your target directory, run "book sm"
Summary will be resolved.